# Automatic indentation on Eclipse PDT when copy-pasting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

This is a simple question :

Is there any automatic indentation alignment on Eclipse PDT when you do a copy-paste ?

Because it doesn't work on my installation (raw copy-paste), but maybe this is because I use tabs instead of spaces, so I want to know if it will work if I switch to spaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then I guess the answer is : no, this functionnality doesn't exists yet. I've moved to PhpStorm and I'm more than happy.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, PhpStorm has this functionnality.

Comment: This is a super old post but since this is still the accepted answer I figure I'd note that Eclipse does have this feature now. For PHP development it is found under Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Editor -> Typing -> "When Pasting" Adjust Indentation.

Answer (score 28):

Actually, such a function exists now for eclipse ***CDT***. In preferences : C++ -> Editor -> Typing, "when pasting", "adjust indentation".

Perhaps it is the same for PDT ?

Comment: (I know this question is 1 year old, question found via google, I answer for other googlers)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though the question is a year old, it still hold given no solution was found. I'll check that out if I open PDT again.

Comment: @Matthieu Found this searching on Google and solved my problem. You should accept his answer.

Comment: @fbafelipe The question was for Eclipse **PDT** (and last time I checked there was no such functionnality)

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Last time I checked (just now *g*), the same feature is available for the PHP Editor (although it's using global indentation and not the project specific one on my system).

Comment: The same functionality exists for Java. In preferences : Java -> Editor -> Typing, "when pasting", "adjust indentation".

Answer (score 6):

I don't know specifically about PDT, but normally you can indent code with `Ctrl + i`, and format code with `Ctrl + Shift + f` (under `Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter` you can specify how the formatter should work).

You can even select multiple files in the navigator and select `Source -> Format` to format several files then.

Comment: Yep, but I would like that to be performed on a "paste" automatically.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much, it has been a trouble to redefine the indentation by hand after copy paste! This solution Works great for me!

Comment: Well, together it's actually just a slight roll of the wrist from `ctrl + v` to `ctrl + shift + f` @MatthieuNapoli. :)

Answer (score 6):

Tony Vermeiren had a suggestion that worked for me
(from https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351771#c17)

open workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.php.ui.prefs

add "smartPaste=false" at the end

save & restart eclipse

Comment: "smartPaste" lol Yes it screw up my format in a very smart way with any interface to disabled that so so smart piece of shcode, is there a conspiracy or something for pushing bugs and ppor formating tools in eclipse? Why eclipse developers hate the other developers so much.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was loosing my mind. Would give you some of my reputation points, but I can see you have much more of them than me :-)

Comment: For CDT, replace "php" with "cdt". And as the author has said, do not forget to save the file and restart eclipse. This is a big time saver.

Answer (score 0):

A similar idea to Davids is the use of Save actions: in the Preferences selecting Java/Editor/Save actions you can define an action to format the java code files during saves. It would solve the paste format problems during the save.

If you manage codes with different coding standards, where this formatting might have problems, define multiple formats, on a per-project basis (using the Project properties window).

Comment: There is no such option in Eclipse PHP ("PHP/Editor/Save actions"). Lucky Java. But still it would be on save, this is too bad it doesn't exists on a paste...

Comment: Sorry - I missed PDT for PDE. I hate these acronyms :).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: uncheck "C/C++->Editor->Typing->Adjust indentation"**

*Explanation:*

**When i copy paste the following:**

[image: copyPasteMakredText]

**And "C/C++->Editor->Typing->Adjust indentation" checked**

[image]

**The result is that the second line has unwanted indentation:**

[image]

**To fix this just uncheck "C/C++->Editor->Typing->Adjust indentation"**